# Обработка нескольких Either

Tags: scala

Имеется 3 метода возвращающие Either, которые необходимо вызывать последовательно и если предыдущий вернул Right. Вернуть надо только результат последнего Either. Как правильно их обработать, чтобы не потерять Left, в случае возникновения ошибки и чтобы не было вложенности вида Either[Either[Either...]]].

```
def doSmth1: Either[Exception, String] = {}
def doSmth2: Either[Exception, String] = {}
def doSmth3: Either[Exception, String] = {}
```

Пробовал обрабатывать так:

```
doSmth1.map(s1 => {/** do something */
  doSmth2.map({
    doSmth3.map({
      //do something
    })
  })
})
```

Но вложенность получается Either[Either[Either...]]].
Можно обрабатывать через for comprehensions:

```
for (
  s1 <- doSmth1
  s2 <- doSmth2
  s3 <- doSmth3
) yield
```

Как вычислить Either без получения вложенностей?

Comment: Так чем не устраивает вариант с for? С ним вложенности не будет

Comment: @extrn я не совсем был уверен, что при возникновении Left, for comprehensions выбросит его.

Comment: for comprehension это синтаксический сахар для применения метода `flatMap` (в основном), а в нем у `Either` прописано как раз нужное вам поведение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы не было вложенности, можно воспользоваться методом [`Either.flatten`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/util/Either.html#flatten%5BA1%3E:A,B1%5D(implicitev:B%3C:%3Cscala.util.Either%5BA1,B1%5D):scala.util.Either%5BA1,B1%5D).

```
doSmth1.map(s1 =>
  doSmth2.map(s2 =>
    doSmth3.map(s3 => /* do something with s1, s2, */ s3)
  ).flatten
).flatten
```

А еще лучше методом, который объединяет `map` и `flatten`

```
doSmth1.flatMap(s1 =>
  doSmth2.flatMap(s2 =>
    doSmth3.map(s3 => /* do something with s1, s2, */ s3)
  )
)
```

Примерно такой код и сгенерирует компилятор при использовании следующей конструкции

```
for {
  s1 <- doSmth1
  s2 <- doSmth2
  s3 <- doSmth3
} yield /* do something with s1, s2, */ s3
```

Для вашего же случая, когда `s1` и `s2` не важны, а `s3` используется без изменения, получаем следующее выражение, применив тождественные преобразования

```
doSmth1 flatMap (_ => doSmth2) flatMap (_ => doSmth3)
```

Можете выбрать любой вариант, но я бы остановился на for comprehension из за его простоты.